# SSO with Windows credentials on JOSSO server

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, josso

I’m currently trying to extend our SSO solution. My company uses a JOSSO server, which run on Tomcat, to enable a single sign-on for users. Now I want to use the users Windows credentials to automatically login to the JOSSO server. I've researched various means ie. Kerberos, Spnego and Windows Integrated Authentication but I have no clue how they work together.

Could anyone tell me which physical components I need and how they rough communicate with each other?

Comment: I have written an authenticator and realm for Tomcat which covers your need. All you need is an Active Directory and machines participating there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer michael-o. Can you please provide me with more details. I'm new in this area and very confused ;).

Comment: Have a look: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/ Though it requires that your environment is ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

physical components and their working-together should be visible here:

http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Architecture+Overview

[image]

Since Kerberos is mixed with NTLM in Windows

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager#Availability_and_use_of_NTLM

> Microsoft has added the NTLM hash to its implementation of the
>   Kerberos protocol to improve inter-operability

it may not be obvious from the usage, which actual SSO technology runs underneath.

You should be happy with the following pages e.g.:

1. http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Windows+Authentication+Setup

> Testing Windows Authentication Log-in to a Windows workstation
>   associated with the Active Directory domain using the previously
>   created account (i.e. user1). Open an Internet Explorer instance and
>   access a JOSSO-protected resource URL. You should be granted access to
>   the protected resource transparently without any prompt for username
>   and password.

2. http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Setup+JOSSO+Agent+%28SP%29

> Normally you will install an agent in each container that will host
>   SSO partner applications. For example, if you have applications
>   deployed on Tomcat and JBoss, you will have to install an agent in
>   each container. Agents are part of the Service Provider (partner
>   application) runtime environment.

3. e.g. (depending on your web container selected from previous page) http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Setup+JOSSO+Agent+-+Tomcat+6.0

> Using this configuration you can set : The Gateway Login URL, where
>   the Single Sign-On Agent will redirect the user on protected resource
>   access request so that he can authenticate. The Gateway Logout URL,
>   where the Single Sign-On Agent will redirect the user on logout
>   request. The concrete Service Locator to be used to invoke the
>   services of the Single Sign-On Gateway. The Single Sign-On partner
>   applications This configuration file defines only one partner
>   application associated with the /partnerapp web context. This means
>   that the web application associated with the /partnerapp web context
>   will be put behind the Single Sign-On. You can define other partner
>   applications.